# DOM: Iterate over elements excluding nested elements that match the same selector

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

(PLEASE NO JQUERY)
Let's say I have the following tree. I want to iterate over elements that match `querySelectorAll('div.bar')` starting from `div.foo`, but not over children that match the same selector. How do I do that?

```
div.foo
  div.bar -- select
  div.bar -- select
    div.bar -- skip
    div.bar -- skip
  div.damnSon
    div.bar -- select
    div.bar -- select
       div.bar --skip
  div.bar -- select
    div.bar -- skip
```

`TreeWalker` is a no-go because

- it rejects the element entirely, while I still want to process it, just not it's children
- it only works on visible elements, while I may be iterating over hidden ones too
  `NodeIterator` don't work either because of the same issues and it iterates over children all the same, even when you reject the parent.

Most ideal case would be to somehow get the result of `querySelector` that isn't flat. Then I'd just loop over them without having to concern myself with nested properties.

Comment: Loop over and check if class is in a parent chain element...

Comment: @Jonasw That will not work. First of all, you are asking to perform a sub-iteration up the tree on EVERY single matched element, to see if it maybe contains the parent and then another iteration down on call to `parent.containsNode`. Second if I call this from a root element with the same selector ALL elements will not pass the check, unless I explicitly stop the loop up on the root element, which makes it even more inefficient.

Comment: I don't see pure CSS selectors getting you very far here, because of the non-existence of a "parent selector", and because `:not()` only takes simple selectors, and is not suited to express "if not in" constellations in more complex trees. // Can you go into a little more detail as to what you eventually want to do with those elements? Two of the three problems your self-answer is now pointing out should have rather been formulated as restrictions in the question itself already, it seems to me. So "what else" is there ...?

Comment: Having said that about CSS selectors, not completely sure if I interpreted your DOM structure correctly regarding the nesting, and neither how many of your requirements that would actually fulfill, this is how far same relatively easy CSS could get you: https://jsfiddle.net/xf3uec7o/3/ ... but that's just applying some borders for visual effect and example purposes, it likely won't give you the desired "non-flat" result to iterate over in any context where you'd use CSS selectors to build up a JS data structure for further processing.

Comment: If you want to reconstruct the entire tree while simply discarding elements that match the selector .bar .bar, you're going to have to do exactly that - manually. The set of elements matched by a selector is flat by design - because it's a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have come up with the following alcoholic method:

```
let nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
let node;
while(node = nodeIterator.nextNode()){
  if (node.matches('.bar .bar')) {
    //skip
  } else if (node.matches('.bar')) {
    //do things
  }
}
```

The problems with this are:

- it's slow - especially in SVGs or anything that has many elements
- it's still flat.
- it will break if `div.foo` (i.e. my root element) is itself nested inside (`div.bar`)

If anyone can advise a better method, that'd be much appreciated.

---

UPDATE:
Ok so I came up with the following method, that sort of solves the last point without being that much more inefficient:

```
let bars = root.getElementsByClassName('bar');
let excludedChildren = [];
for(let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++){
  let children = bars[i].getElementsByClassName('bar');
  if(children.length>0) Array.prototype.push.apply(excludedChildren, children);
}
bars = bars.filter(e=>!excludedChildren.includes(e));
bars.forEach(e=>{
  //do stuff
});
```

---

UPDATE:
Time to close this old sh*t up, [here is my final solution](https://codepen.io/megakoresh/pen/RgLRXK?editors=0010). Has worked for a month now in production without any problems. Of course this will not be able to handle some very complex cases, but it's extensible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elems=Array.prototype.filter.call(querySelectorAll('div.bar'),function(el){
  var foochild=false;
  while(el=el.parent){
    if(el.classList.contains("bar") return false;//fail as its a div.bar children
    if(el.classList.contains("foo")) foochild=true;//were a children of foo
   }
   return foochild;
});
```

Simply filter the div.bars concerning their parents in the dom tree.

---

Another way would be iterating through all direct foo childs:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.foo"),function iterate(foo){
  for(var i=0;i<foo.children.length){
   var child=foo.children[i];
   if(child.classList.contains("bar")){
     //weve found a bar
   }else{
    iterate(child);//find subbars
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is even slower than my solution, and it will not work if `div.foo` (i.e. my root) is itself nested in a `div.bar`.

Comment: Actually neither will mine now that I think of it. Need to add that to the answer.

Comment: @megakoresh is it really slower? I think it depends on the nodes / div.bar relation...

Comment: Your updated method relies on `foo.children`, which is only containing direct children. This will exclude the `div.bar`s inside the `div.damnSon`.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the nested elements with a `:not` in the CSS selector like:

```js
querySelectorAll('div.bar:not(div.bar div.bar)')
```

See it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/mstringer/pen/VwgWayp) or run the snippet:

```js
let foo = document.querySelector("div.foo");
let bars = foo.querySelectorAll("div.bar:not(div.bar div.bar)");
bars.forEach((div) => {
  div.style.border = "3px solid black";
  div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
});
```

```css
div {
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.foo {
  width: 200px;
}
.bar::before {
  content: "bar";
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="damnSon">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```